# Deriving intersection of two truth sets

Tags: propositional-calculus

$ \newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}$

Let $A = \Set{x}{P(x)}$, $B = \Set{x}{Q(x)}$. We know by definition that

$$ A \setminus B = \Set{x}{P(x) \land \lnot Q(x)}.$$

Since $X \cap Y = X \setminus (X \setminus Y)$ for two sets $X$ and $Y$ then following should hold true.

\begin{align}
& A \cap B = \\
& A \setminus (A \setminus B) = \\
& \Set{x}{P(x)} \setminus (\Set{x}{P(x) \land \lnot Q(x)}) = \\
&\Set{x}{P(x) \land \lnot(P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))} = \\
& \Set{x}{P(x) \land \lnot P(x) \lor Q(x)} = \Set{x}{Q(x)}
\end{align}

Where is the mistake? The answer should be $\Set{x}{P(x) \land Q(x)}$. Is the intersection formula wrong or is it not generally true that

$$ \Set{x}{\varphi(x)} \setminus \Set{x}{\psi(x)} = \Set{x}{\varphi(x) \land \lnot \psi(x)} $$

for sentences $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$?

Comment: $P(x) \wedge \neg (P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x)) = P(x) \wedge (\neg P(x) \vee Q(x)) = (P(x) \wedge \neg P(x)) \vee (P(x) \wedge Q(x)) = P(x) \wedge Q(x))$.  So your mistake is in the fourth to fifth line in the deductions above.

Comment: What a silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error originated in the line preceding "Where is the mistake?"; you had crucially left out a pair of parentheses. So, **correction**: $ \newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}$
\begin{align}
& A \setminus (A \setminus B) \\
= &\Set{x}{P(x) \land \lnot(P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))} \\
= & \Set{x}{P(x) \land (\lnot P(x) \lor Q(x))}\\
= & \Set{x}{(P(x) \land \lnot P(x)) \lor (P(x) \land Q(x))}\\
= & \Set{x}{P(x) \land Q(x)}.
\end{align}